# multiprocessing.dummy doesn't improve speed

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

From other posts, I read that all you need to do for multi threading in python is to use this simple code

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(8) 
results = pool.map(extract_from_file, file_list)
```

to replace

```
for file in file_list:
   extract_from_file(file)
```

In my case, extract_from_file(file) reads in a very long file and cuts it into interesting sequences, that are saved in different folders.

In my case, the multi threading brings no speed improvement at all. However, what I find strange is that I can manually split up the list and just open Spyder several times and run multiple instances of python without multi threading, which leads to a big speed improvement. Does that proof anything, i.e. can I assume that my function can be multi threaded, just not with this specific library?

Comment: "that are saved in different folders" - do any of these overlap? Are the different threads ever going to be trying to save to the same files at the same time?

Comment: no, all the saved files are distinct (they contain the original file name in their names). However, they are saved in the same folders.

Comment: Also, you might want to check your resources, specifically how many disk operations are taking place. If the bottleneck is your storage io it makes sense that multiprocessing won't help.

Comment: To check that, I tried running multiple Spyder instances with single thread code, while dividing up the files manually. This improves the speed significantly, so the resource limit is not reached.

Comment: I see what you mean. Doesn't sound like its your storage. Could you provide more details about or share the `extract_from_file` function? Is it possible the function is referencing or depending on common objects? You could also try tracking the progress of each instance e.g., with time-stamped prints.